# Is there a way to paste a right regex to the minibuffer after M-x isearch-forward-regexp

Tags: emacs

The right regex I copied:

```
\(.\)
```

What I pasted after M-x isearch-forward-regexp:

```
\\(\.\\)
```

Is there a way to solve that?

Answer (score 3):

`isearch-yank-pop` causes the yanked text to be `regexp-quote`d if a regexp search is in progress. The assumption is that whatever you are yanking is text to find verbatim, and not part of a regexp.

The solution is to *edit* the search pattern (<kbd>M-e</kbd>), and *then* yank the text into the minibuffer (<kbd>C-y</kbd>).

Answer (score 1):

1. What @phils said.  (Yanking in vanilla Isearch during regexp search applies `regexp-quote`.)
2. If you use library [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) then:

   - Whether that automatic `regexp-quote`-ing is done or not is controlled by option **`isearchp-regexp-quote-yank-flag`**.
   - You can toggle that option value anytime during isearch using **`` C-` ``** (command `isearchp-toggle-regexp-quote-yank`).